# path resolution of include

Tags: c, gcc

Is there a definitive way to see where a given `#include <example.h>` resolves to? I have a `#include <linux/unistd.h>` in my code but I don't know which `unistd.h` is being used.

Comment: Does it matter which unistd? That file tends to be fairly standard: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/unistd.h.html

Comment: So that's what the `std` stands for :P

Comment: Including `<linux/unistd.h>` instead of simply `<unistd.h>` is most probably a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the `-E` command line option to get the preprocessor output, it will tell you the full path to every header file included, including those included by other headers.  For example:

```
$ cat test.c
#include <unistd.h>
$ gcc -E test.c
# 1 "test.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "test.c"
# 1 "/usr/include/unistd.h" 1 3 4
# 71 "/usr/include/unistd.h" 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/_types.h" 1 3 4
# 27 "/usr/include/_types.h" 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/sys/_types.h" 1 3 4
# 32 "/usr/include/sys/_types.h" 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h" 1 3 4
# 33 "/usr/include/sys/_types.h" 2 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/machine/_types.h" 1 3 4
# 34 "/usr/include/machine/_types.h" 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/i386/_types.h" 1 3 4
# 37 "/usr/include/i386/_types.h" 3 4
typedef signed char __int8_t;

(lots more output)
```

So in this case, the header that's being used is `/usr/include/unistd.h`.

Answer (score 0):

From the [GCC documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html),

> On a normal Unix system, if you do not
>   instruct it otherwise, it will look
>   for headers requested with #include
>    in:
>
> ```
>  /usr/local/include
>  libdir/gcc/target/version/include
>  /usr/target/include
>  /usr/include
> ```
>
> In the above, target is the canonical
>   name of the system GCC was configured
>   to compile code for; often but not
>   always the same as the canonical name
>   of the system it runs on. version is
>   the version of GCC in use.
>
> You can add to this list with the
>   -Idir command line option. All the directories named by -I are searched,
>   in left-to-right order, before the
>   default directories. The only
>   exception is when dir is already
>   searched by default. In this case, the
>   option is ignored and the search order
>   for system directories remains
>   unchanged.

So unless you're adding the -I (capital eye, not ell) switch, the version included is the version found in the first of those directories that holds it.